# What is the best way to use Vuetify skeleton on Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm kinda new to Vue, Nuxt, and Vuetify and their aspects. I'm working on a Nuxt project with Vuetify and wanna use its skeleton loader but it's kinda messy. right now I use this pattern
template:

```vue
<v-skeleton-loader :loading="isLoading" type"card">
    <mycomponent />
</v-skeleton-loader>
```

### script

```vue
import skeleton from '@plugins/mixins/skeleton.js
export default {
    mixins:[skeleton]
}
```

### skeleton.js

```vue
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            loading: null
        }
    },
    computed:{
        isLoading(){
            return this.loading
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.loading = true
    },
    mounted(){
        this.loading = false
    }
}
```

when I first used it it was working perfectly. i had a static page and each of its components had their own skeleton and every time i loaded the page it would show their skeleton until they were loaded.
BUT.... as I started using this pattern on different pages i found out that it has many flaws!!

- it only shows the skeleton when the page is refreshed!
- won't show when I add components or data to the page! for example, an Axios call to get the product
- it won't work when changing between routes
- and so on ...

So, my question is, What's the best and most practical way to use the skeleton loader! i had a page with a `v-for` loop through a component and the component had its own skeleton in its template. it only show skeleton on refresh!
like this:

```
<div v-for="i in 10" :key="i">
    <mycomp />
</div>
```

mycomp:

```
<v-skeleton-loader :loading="isLoading" type"card">
    // components html codes
</v-skeleton-loader>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would you suggest to create skeleton component. And in main component most of apps do this stuff, where the amount of skeleton is fixed or limited by pagination:

```
<template v-if="loading">
  <skeleton v-for="i in 10" :key="i" />
</template>
<template v-else>
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about patterns, finally decided to make component for each skeleton and show it with `v-if` as you suggested. but the problem is on pages without `fetch` or axios call. on those i mutated my isLoading by `created` & `mounted` . but it only works properly on page refresh! for example i load page and see skeleton, click on a link and go to new page, then hit back on return button. and there is no skeleton.

Comment: I would suggest to use vuex, where you can store both data and `loading` bool. That approach will prevent unwanted loaders